# Get the email of my friends using Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Is there any possible way from which i can access my friends email using php-sdk? Assuming that I am logged in is it possible to see the same info through a php script .What i want to do is send a gmail invite to all my friends on facebook using graph.facebook.com/$id/
it asks for a access token please help me with it .

Answer (score 0):

1. While login, set the permissions for email also, and you would be able to access the email

   ```
   $facebook->api('/FRIEND_ID?fields=email')
   ```
2. for access token , use -

   ```
   $facebook->getAccessToken()
   ```